# Reflection get all GenericParameterAttributes

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to get all `GenericParameterAttributes` for generic parameter T in MClass

```
public class MClass<T>:IEnumerable<T> where T : class,IComparable, new()
    {
//some body here
 }
```

So i try it in this way:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("M.dll");
            Type some_type = asm.GetType("M.MClass`1");

            Type[] generic_args = { typeof(MyTestClass) };
            if (some_type.IsGenericType)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Generic Type: {0}", some_type.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Where T : {0}", some_type.GetGenericArguments()[0].GenericParameterAttributes);
                some_type = some_type.MakeGenericType(generic_args);
            }
```

But in some reason propherty GenericParameterAttributes show that T must be class with default constructor but doest't show that T also must have IComparable
also tried in this way :

this worked but DONT FORGET TO REBUILT project after changed)

```
     static void Main()
            {
               Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("M.dll");
                Type some_type = asm.GetType("M.MClass`1");

                if (some_type.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var generic_argument =some_type.GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
                    var generic_parameter_constraints =generic_argument.GetGenericParameterConstraints();
                    Console.WriteLine(generic_parameter_constraints.Length);
                    Console.ReadLine();
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke [`GetGenericParameterConstraints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx) on the generic argument type like this:

```
var generic_argument =
    some_type
    .GetGenericArguments()[0]; //This will give you the generic argument which is T in your example.

var generic_parameter_constraints =
    generic_argument
    .GetGenericParameterConstraints(); //This will give you an array of types that present the type constraints on the generic argument T
```

In your case `generic_parameter_constraints` would contain an array of `Type` that has a single element which is `typeof(IComparable)`.

Comment: tried allready...
GetGenericParameterConstraints() return empty array

Comment: You called this method on which object?

Comment: Exactly as you write
some_type.GetGenericArguments()[0] return T

Comment: And then you invoke `GetGenericParameterConstraints` on `generic_argument `? or on `some_type`?

Comment: copy past your answer and `generic_parameter_constraints.Lengh` = 0

Comment: I actually tested the code before posting. Maybe your real code is different that the one in the question. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I changed  code in question as you recommended and still 0